# Oracle : Grant Create table in another schema?

Tags: oracle

I have two users : Schema1 and Schema2

How to grant Create Table privilege On Schema2 to Schema1 ?

I have been turning around and I got confused.
I tried :

From Schema2 I tried,

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO SCHEMA1 WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

But it seems like this grants Creating table to Schema1 in its own Schema and not in the Schema2.

Any ideas please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only other way to allow a non-DBA user to create a table in another schema is to give the user the `CREATE ANY TABLE` system privilege.

This privilege can only be given to `SCHEMA1 by a user having the CREATE ANY PRIVILEGE` privilege.

Comment: More precisely a user with `GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE` privilege - the DBA role has this privilege, of course.

Comment: So if there is also a Schema3 and 4, the schema1 can now create tables not only in schema2, but also in schema3 and 4?

Comment: This seems like a good middle-ground solution: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13320/grant-create-permission-on-a-specific-schema-in-oracle-11g

Answer (score 7):

You want to grant `create ANY table`:

```
grant create any table to schema1;
```

The `any` "modifier" allows to create tables in other than own schemas.

Answer (score 4):

Better solution (minimizes the security threat that comes with `CREATE ANY TABLE` privilege...)

- Create a procedure on schema2 that takes a table definition as a
  "input" parameter (e.g. p_tab_def in varchar2(4000).
- Inside put an execute_immediate(p_tab_def); statement. You MUST check the p_tab_def first in order to defend yourself from other DDL statements than
  "CREATE TABLE [...]". (e.g. you could use a simple check by checking first two
  words -> it must be "CREATE TABLE").
- `GRANT EXECUTE ON schema2.procedure_name TO schema1;`

It's a simple concept ... I've used such concepts in my previous job.

Comment: This works only in anonymous blocks. Attempt to execute "create table" within a schema2 procedure by schema1 requires 'AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS
' at the beginning of the proc.

Comment: @access_granted I believe this is only if `create table` is granted via role. If they are direct user grants, should be able to `authid definer` in the SP DDL. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411898/execute-dynamic-ddl-in-pl-sql-procedure-through-definer-role-permissions