# Grant permissions on schema to specific schema in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl

I would like to know if there is a way to grant permissions to, for example, create table on a schema, from a different user. 
I want to do this without granting DBA role, nor granting "ANY" permissions (*grant create any table to XXXX*).

Comment: [The short answer is no](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21413042/266304), but you could do this with a stored procedure that executes dynamic SQL; it's a bit messy and potentially could leave security holes (if implemented badly). What is the objection to `create any`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle : Grant Create table in another schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412747/oracle-grant-create-table-in-another-schema)

Comment: As I said, the reason why this is not a duplicate is because I don't want to use * ANY *, and the reason why I don't want to use * ANY * is because I want to individually control those schemas in which the user can create tables.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this](http://pastebin.com/Neaqp6U8) occasionally to satisfy devs who want a read-only account. This will create DDL that will give appropriate select or execute permissions. It would not be difficult to modify that to include update and delete.