# Oracle - deploying objects into a different schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c

*I'm surprised I haven't been able to find this question on the site already.  Apologies if it turns out to be a duplicate!*

In Oracle (10 upwards) is it possible for `USER_A` to deploy objects in `USER_B`'s schema?

For example, assuming I am logged in as `USER_B`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE user_a.my_example_pkg IS

   PROCEDURE Make_Log;
   PROCEDURE Init;

END user_a.my_example_pkg;
```

I get an `ORA-1031: insufficient privileges` response when I deploy.

I know that it is possible to log in as `USER_A` to deploy the package, and yes I can do that.  But the point is that on my database, someone appears to have modified a package "across the schema" in this way.  And I need to figure out how they did it!!

I'm fairly sure that the privilege exists, but I can't find what it is.  Moreover, if there are many privileges which allow this to be done, it would be a bonus to get an exhaustive list of what those privileges are.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412747/oracle-grant-create-table-in-another-schema

Comment: `t possible for USER_A to deploy objects in USER_B's` - Question is why do you want to duplicate the code when you can simply grant `execute` permission to package in `USER_A` schema to `USER_B` schema ? And in worst case you want to do it then why are you using schema alias infront of package name. You are anyways executing the whole package so whats the point ?

Comment: @XING suggest you read the question before answering next time.  Your answer is in the question

Comment: Is it possible that someone simply connected as `user_b` and created the package there by mistake? How do you know they were connected as `user_a` at the time and used special privileges to create it?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Not just possible, it's probable. But nobody's owning up to it. Also, the audit logs suggest that `user_b` wasn't connected at the time. Do you know of a way I can figure out who redeployed the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to look for the `ANY` privileges

- `CREATE PROCEDURE` lets you create procedures in your schema.  `CREATE ANY PROCEDURE` lets you create procedures in any schema.
- `CREATE TABLE` lets you create tables in your schema.  `CREATE ANY TABLE` lets you create tables in any schema.
- `CREATE VIEW` lets you create views in your schema.  `CREATE ANY VIEW` lets you create views in any schema.

For any of the `CREATE` privileges, there is a corresponding `CREATE ANY` privilege.  Those `ANY` privileges are **extremely** powerful and really shouldn't be given to anyone other than a DBA since it would allow you to do things like create procedures owned by highly privileged users that can do anything a DBA could do.

Comment: Yeah - I know they're high-level privileges, which is why I'm keen to find out who has them!!  Thanks for the clear answer.